# Could not get item with id exception when opening a page with Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

We are facing an odd error when opening a page in Experience Editor:

> An error occurred. [Log message: Could not get item with
>   id:{EA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1} from database:master]

[image]

The GUID listed, is the GUID of the page and comes up when you search for the item, so not sure what is causing the error.

[image]

Here is a snipit of the logs that are showing the error, the error is logged multiple times. Any suggestions, what could be the issue?

> 2212 12:16:53 ERROR Could not get item with
>   id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from database:master
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Could not get
>   item with id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from
>   database:master Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_Item()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.EnableDesigning.CanDesign.GetState()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.Common.ToggleCapabilityRequest.GetControlState()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorControlStateRequest`1.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)
>
> 6704 12:16:56 ERROR Could not get item with
>   id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from database:master
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Could not get
>   item with id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from
>   database:master Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_Item()
>   at
>   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Requests.CheckLimitedDevice.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)
>
> 6928 12:16:56 ERROR Could not get item with
>   id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from database:master
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Could not get
>   item with id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from
>   database:master Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_Item()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_DeviceItem()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.SelectDevice.DeviceIconLabelRequest.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)
>
> 4084 12:16:56 ERROR Could not get item with
>   id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from database:master
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Could not get
>   item with id:%7bEA2F948D-613B-4392-837E-96FC933FEFE1%7d from
>   database:master Source: Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_Item()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Requests.ExperienceEditor.ItemHasActiveTestRequest.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)

Comment: have you tried rebulding indexes and link database?

Comment: Yes, tried rebuilding indexes. we are running Solr and we are not experiencing any other issues that could be pointing to the cores. I just tried rebuilding the links database but no success.

Comment: 1) Check that user in Experience Editor has right to this item 2) Check that item is publishable.

Comment: The error happens with the admin account that has not been modified. The page is publishable and accessible on our CD server.

Comment: We currently have a support ticket open with Sitecore and waiting to hear from them after they review our log files. Will provide update when I receive one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to a corrupted install of the SC Hotfix 195920-1 for Experience Editor. Once I reinstalled the hotfix, the issue went away.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/502008